# Scala: How to create a new list from operation on adjacent elements of a list

Tags: scala

If I have a list like List(1,2,3,4), I want to create a new list that will be equivalent to,

List(1+2, 3+4) = List(3,7)

I need some opeartion to add adjacent numbers in a list and create new list from it. I looked at map, reduceLeft, foldLeft operations but could not find something that would accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `grouped`, which partitions the list into sublists of a given size. For example:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).grouped(2).map(_.sum).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 7)
```

Note that `grouped` returns an iterator, so you need to call something like `toList` if you want a collection. Also note that if your list doesn't have an even number of elements (or more generally isn't evenly divisible by the argument to `grouped`), the final list returned by the iterator may contain fewer elements than the rest.